# Laravel model inheritance

Tags: php, model, laravel, laravel-4

I am using the Toddish/Verify library for Laravel as it includes 99% of what I need for my project. All I need is to add some fields.

I have added them in a migration, and I want to add them also to mass creation:

```
use Toddish\Verify\Models\User as VerifyUser;

class User extends VerifyUser
{
    public function __construct () {
        array_merge ($this->fillable, array(
            'salutation', 'title', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'phonenumber', 'mobilenumber'
        ));
    }
}
```

However, when I run my creation test:

```
public function testUserCreation () {
    $user = User::create(
        [
            'username' => 'testusername',
            'email' => 'email@test.com',
            'password' => 'testpassword',
            'salutation' => 'MrTest',
            'title' => 'MScTest',
            'firstname' => 'Testfirstname',
            'lastname' => 'Testlastname',
            'phonenumber' => 'testPhoneNumber',
            'mobilenumber' => 'testMobileNumber',
        ]
    );
    $this->assertEquals($user->salutation, 'MrTest');
    $this->assertEquals($user->title, 'MScTest');
    $this->assertEquals($user->firstname, 'Testfirstname');
    $this->assertEquals($user->lastname, 'Testlastname');
    $this->assertEquals($user->phonenumber, 'testPhoneNumber');
    $this->assertEquals($user->mobilenumber, 'testMobileNumber');
}
```

I get this:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 users.username may not be NULL (SQL: insert into "users" ("updated_at", "created_at") values (2014-03-03 09:57:41, 2014-03-03 09:57:41))
```

in all tests that involve user creation, as if it had forgotten about the parents attributes when saving the model.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can we see the users model

Comment: https://github.com/Toddish/Verify-L4/blob/master/src/Toddish/Verify/Models/User.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're overriding what I assume is the Eloquent constructor, so the values are never getting passed.

Change `__construct` to look like the following.

```
public function __construct(array $attributes = array())
{
    parent::__construct($attributes);

    array_merge ($this->fillable, array(
        'salutation', 'title', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'phonenumber', 'mobilenumber'
    ));
}
```

The `Model::create` method will actually create a new instance of the model and pass the array into the __construct. You're overriding this and preventing it from passing the information through.

**Note** If you decide to override core methods like you've done here, always check inheritance and make sure you aren't breaking anything.

Comment: Thanks, missed that for some reason. I'll accept this as the answer when I can.

Comment: No problem, I recently did a similar thing and totally ballsed up all of my models as they extended my custom class aha.